# Upper bound of product of two Gaussian distributed variables

Tags: probability, statistics, asymptotics

I wasn't sure whether this question should be asked on Computer Science or Math Stack Exchange, so I will ask first here.

Having $X_i \sim N(0,I_n)$, s.t. $X_i \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $i \in \{1,...,d\}$ and with high probability $\langle X_i, X_i \rangle = O(n)$, where every two $X_i,X_j$ are independent from each other, show that with high probability upper bound of the inner product is:
$$|\langle X_i, X_j \rangle| \le O(\sqrt{n \log{d}})$$ where $ d \ge n$

Comment: What exactly is the statement you want to prove (with regard to $d$)? You want the guarantee to hold simultaneously for all $1\leq i\neq j\leq d$, I assume?

Comment: Yes, that inequality, in regard to both $d$ and $n.$

Comment: But, it is not explicitly said that $i \ne j$, so you should include that one as well.

Comment: 1). There is no way to include $i=j$, since for $i=j$ we actually have $\langle X_i,X_i\rangle = \Theta(n)$ w.h.p.; and 2). my question is whether you ask for the inequality to hold *simutaneously* w.h.p. ($\Pr[\forall i\neq j, ...] \geq .9$)

Comment: Yes, I am asking for that! Not sure how I should start nor work on it, regarding probability bound, we mentioned only Chernoff bounds in the lectures, but not explicitly for this case.

Comment: @As a start, can you prove that $\mathbb{E}[\langle X_i, X_j\rangle^2] = n$ for $i\neq j$ (by conditioning on $Y$ first)?